# Why are Ruby #hash methods randomized?

Tags: ruby

I just noticed that the return value of `#hash` changes each time I start up Ruby:

```
$ irb
2.0.0-p353 :001 > "".hash
2313425349783613115
2.0.0-p353 :002 > exit

$ irb
2.0.0-p353 :001 > "".hash
4543564897974813688
2.0.0-p353 :002 > exit
```

I looked at the MRI source to see why this was happening:

```
st_index_t
rb_str_hash(VALUE str)
{
    int e = ENCODING_GET(str);
    if (e && rb_enc_str_coderange(str) == ENC_CODERANGE_7BIT) {
    e = 0;
    }
    return rb_memhash((const void *)RSTRING_PTR(str), RSTRING_LEN(str)) ^ e;
}
```

It turns out `rb_memhash` is defined in `random.c`:

```
st_index_t
rb_memhash(const void *ptr, long len)
{
    sip_uint64_t h = sip_hash24(sipseed.key, ptr, len);
#ifdef HAVE_UINT64_T
    return (st_index_t)h;
#else
    return (st_index_t)(h.u32[0] ^ h.u32[1]);
#endif
}
```

And though I can't find what `ruby_sip_hash24` is, I assume that it's not a deterministic function.

After a bit of messing around, I managed to find [this commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/04739ba61744046ac145b384aa9053429c80142f) by Tanaka Akira that changes `rb_str_hash` to use `rb_memhash` due to "avoid algorithmic complexity attacks". What does that mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Well researched question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the commit message said, it is due to avoid **[algorithmic complexity attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_complexity_attack)**.

> An **algorithmic complexity attack** is a form of computer attack that
>   exploits known cases in which an algorithm used in a piece of software
>   will exhibit worst case behavior. This type of attack can be used to
>   achieve a **denial-of-service**.

By using `rb_memhash`, the hash result will be randomized every time you start a new ruby execution context. Otherwise, if is not randomized, the attacker know the algorithm and could find out the worst case behavior which could used as the **[DoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)** Attack.